# Error running Jest on CircleCI: "npm test died unexpectedly"

Tags: node.js, jestjs, circleci

Running my Jest test suite on CircleCI is *much* slower compared to locally, resulting in an error in CircleCI saying `npm test died unexpectedly`.

To give you an idea of the difference in test duration on CircleCI vs. Locally (on a MacBook Air 2012, fwiw):

**CircleCI:**

`97 tests passed (97 total in 25 test suites, run time 123.918s)
npm test died unexpectedly`

**Locally:**

`97 tests passed (97 total in 25 test suites, run time 13.601s)`

The only semi-related piece of information I've found related to Jest and CircleCI is [this issue regarding controlling memory usage](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/535), however I don't *think* the issue I'm experiencing is related, but then again if I knew the issue I wouldn't be here :)

Any ideas what might be going on here, or tips to debug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @cpojer in the [#jest channel](https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/103622435865104384), I was able to reduce the test runtime down to ~21s by running my tests with [`--runInBand`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/12c13459b35c812db7eee6663bf521032316c127/src/cli/processArgs.js#L70), which:

> Run all tests serially in the current process (rather than creating a worker pool of child processes that run tests). This is sometimes useful for debugging, but such use cases are pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

It dies probably because of out of memory. (4 Gb in CircleCI by default) An alternative is to use `--maxWorkers=2` instead of `--runInBand`. `--runInBand` runs all tests in single thread, while you could optimize it by tuning `maxWorkers` such that you won't out of memory and speed up the test.